# Flash animation to preload page (and fade in/out effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, xhtml

My client wants so have a loading animation/movie (already created that in Flash CS5) on the website's start page (root, '/' - the first thing you see when you go to domain.tld).
When the animation's finished it should forward to another page (i.e. the real page with the content), e.g. `domain.tld/somepage.htm`
I can do this with, for example, `getURL()` in Flash and it works fine.

But. Is it possible to kind of preload `domain.tld/somepage.htm` so the content (almost) instantly appears after the loading animation's finished?

Also, a fade-out-fade-in effect would be nice, i.e. the loading animation fades out and the content of `domain.tld/somepage.htm` fades in.

I would assume that would have to be done with JavaScript?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: are you making this site in html or flash?

Comment: I'm using XHTML. PHP for the server-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind for me is External Interface.

When your movie completes, or the user clicks skip, use External Interface to call a JavaScript method from flash. Which can then fade out the container holding the flash.

External Interface is available in both AS3 and AS2.

That should be all you need, hope it helps.